# MySQLi or PHP problems with Microsoft Azure

Tags: php, html, azure, mysqli

I have several pages that inserts values from forms into my MySQLi database. Every insert page is working well except from one. I have tested on two servers, MariaDB and Microsoft Azure "Web app + MySQL", and the nonworking insert page works on MariaDB but not on Azure while all the other insert pages works on Azure. I wonder why the one insert-page doesn't work on Azure, because it works when I test it locally and on MariaDB? May it be a compability issue with Azure, or do I have to add something to my codes that inserts the values into my MySQLi database?

**This is from the nonworking page(on azure) where I fill the values:**

```html
<form action="insertcompanies.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="insertcompanies" onsubmit="return validateForm()">
    <br>
    <b>Project name</b> <br>
    <input type="text" name="company_name" id="company_name">
    <b>Add picture:</b><br>
    <input type="file" name="image" id="image">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Add" />
</form>
```

**This is from the nonworking page(on azure) that inserts the values into my database:**

```html
$company_name = $_POST['company_name'];
$image = addslashes (file_get_contents($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']));
$logo = getimagesize($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']);
$image_type = $logo['mime'];

$q = "INSERT INTO project VALUES('','$company_name','$image','$image_type');";

$r = mysqli_query($mysqli,$q);
if($r)
{ echo "<h1>Project done!</h1>";}
```

When I press the submit button on the first page to insert the values via the second page, I don't get the message "Project done!" from the page that inserts the value into the database. All I see is a blank page.

I was unsure about which codes I would show you, so if you need to see any other codes just tell me!

Comment: Do your have error reporting on? ie. `error_reporting(-1); ini_set( 'display_errors', 1 );` at the top of `insertcompanies.php`? Often a blank page is a sign that you have a syntax or other error somewhere in your code.

Comment: @Sean Yes I have but I don't get any messages, it is still plank. I have also tested to write error_reporting(E_ALL);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be something wrong in your sql stmt. So you got a blank page without any PHP errors.

You can modify your mysqli code to add error output for troubleshooting:

```
if($r){ 
        echo "<h1>Project done!</h1>";
    }else{
        echo "Errno: " . $mysqli->errno . "\n";
        echo "Error: " . $mysqli->error . "\n";
    }
```

As I create a table on MySQL on Azure, the scheme is:

```
CREATE TABLE `project` (
  `Id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `company_name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `image` longblob,
  `image_type` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

try to reproduce your issue.

If I use the sql stmt in your format list :

```
$q = "INSERT INTO project VALUES('','$company_name','$image','$image_type');";
```

I have to define the special id value e.g.

```
$q = "INSERT INTO project VALUES(1,'$company_name','$image','$image_type');";
```

Or I have to modify to:

```
$q = "INSERT INTO project (company_name,image,image_type) VALUES('$company_name','$image','$image_type');";
```